# How to join two tables in PL/SQL without creating a new one

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, ddl

I'm trying to join two tables in PL/SQL but I don't want to create another table. I would like to use "ALTER TABLE".

I want to alter my old table and add one column from another table.  I've tried to use alter table and create the new column, which is the one from the second table.

```
ALTER TABLE TAB1
ADD VAR1 VARCHAR(30);
UPDATE TAB1 A
SET A.VAR1 = B.VAR1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT VAR1 FROM TAB2 B WHERE A.ID = B.ID)
```

The error message is in the "B.VAR1".

Comment: Those are called columns, not "variables"

Comment: Why do you want to store the same data twice, in two separate tables?

Answer (score 0):

```
update tab1 a set
  a.var1 = (select b.var1 
            from tab2 b
            where b.id = a.id
           )
where exists (select null
              from tab2 b
              where b.id = a.id
             );
```

Or:

```
merge into tab1 a
  using (select b.id, b.var1
         from tab2 b
        ) x
  on (x.id = a.id)
when matched then update set
  a.var1 = x.var1;
```

Comment: a question Just clicked through my mind, If we talk about performance perspective, which would work faster UPDATE or MERGE(ignoring the affected no of rows scenario)?

Comment: I don't have any documentation reference, but - from my own experience, MERGE sometimes works faster than UPDATE, @Ankit. In order to find the truth, explain plans should be compared.